# Client side Custom Validator to use

Tags: asp.net, validation

Just want to ask if i can use Custom Validator in client side without using it in server side ?
thanks in advance!

Comment: if u don't want to write javascript validation use validation control from ajaxToolKit

Comment: http://WhatHaveYouTried.com show some effort. Try first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of examples for validation on client side:

- http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation
- http://www.junnark.com/Blog/Detail/using-jquery-validation-with-aspnet-web-forms
- http://encosia.com/using-jquery-validation-with-asp-net-webforms/
- http://encosia.com/asp-net-webforms-validation-groups-with-jquery-validation/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `CustomValidator` control has a property called `ClientValidationFunction`.

Create a Javascript function like so:

```
function YourFunctionName(sender, args) {

    if(x == true) /* put your validation check in here */
    {            
        args.IsValid = true;
        return; 
    }
    else
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
        return;
    }
}
```

Then set the `ClientValidationFunction` property to `YourFunctionName`.

Comment: The official Microsoft example is at the bottom of this page - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use javascript or you can use jquery validation

Comment: you can view it here [link](http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/17/10-useful-jquery-form-validation-techniques-and-tutorials-2/)